# What information is important to include in an About dialog?

Tags: .net, metadata, about-box

What information is important to include in an About dialog?

Definitely:

- Name of the software
- Version
- Copyright notice

Usually:

- Assemblies versions (for .NET applications)

Comment: Community wiki version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366683/how-to-design-a-good-about-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare minimum would be version number, build date (and time), copyright, a way to get at the text of the EULA, creators (either individuals or company), and libraries used.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Atwood himself designed the [perfect About box](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000005.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the product, you might want to have links to the product's website or your company's.
As long as you've got the full version number i don't think you can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The about box is also a good place to show the licensing information.